# Open Source hospital or medical insurance related MIS or Hospital Information System in .NET

Tags: .net, database-design, system

I am currently working on a Hospital Information System for the government and I wanted to know if there is a open source (Even a sample or a base not used worldwide) software or even a sample database available to download to get some fresh ideas. If not, is there any information on design and analysis the processes within the hospitals especially. Any help would near to this topic will be just fine as well, thank you!

Comment: Do you need patient care/diagnoses or facilities management, as the software design will vary considerably between the two.

Comment: This would be a good question for the [Healthcare Industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=0FgbVsKaId7Z_15aCbzplg2) stack exchange. If you're interested, consider joining.

Answer (score 2):

- [HOSxP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOSxP) is a Thai open source healthcare system.
- [OpenClinical](http://www.openclinical.org/opensourceDLD.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_healthcare_software) both have lists of open source healthcare products.
- And here's a few basic data models:

  - [Hospital Admissions](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/hospital_admissions/index.htm)
  - [Hospital Outpatients](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/hospital_outpatients/index.htm)
  - [Hospitals and Patients](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/hospitals_and_patients_for_noor/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

One place I go to for open source database designs is a website called Database Answers.  You can see their section on Healthcare [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/healthcare_models.htm).

This website is in Britain, so the solutions given here may reflect health care there.  And in any event, so should consider these solutions as starting places for your wn design.